# Filter an Object and Return Key in Typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, data-structures, ecmascript-6

I have an object to be filtered and it should return a key that has a specific id. Id is Unique . Need an efficient logic to return this expected output.The Object to be filtered.

```
{
  "a":[{"id":"1123","value":"test1"}],
  "b":[{"id":"1124","value":"test2"}],
  "c":[{"id":"1125","value":"test3"}]
  
}
```

**Input Id**: "1124"

```
Expected Output  : 'b'
```

Comment: Except with a loop I don't understand how we can do it

Comment: Yes we can loop it .Looking for efficient solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efficiencies here:

- break the loop as soon as something is found
- not interested in the object that has the id, only in checking that something there has that id

```js
o = {
  "a":[{"id":"1123","value":"test1"}],
  "b":[{"id":"1124","value":"test2"}],
  "c":[{"id":"1125","value":"test3"}]
  
}
for (key in o) {
  if (o[key].some(x => x.id === '1124')) {
    console.log(key);
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let data  = {
  "a":[{"id":"1123","value":"test1"}],
  "b":[{"id":"1124","value":"test2"}],
  "c":[{"id":"1125","value":"test3"}]
};

let input = "1124";

let result  = Object.entries(data).filter(([k,v]) => v[0].id === input)[0][0];
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks Much. this solution is helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const input = "1124"

const obj = {
  "a":[{"id":"1123","value":"test1"}],
  "b":[{"id":"1124","value":"test2"}],
  "c":[{"id":"1125","value":"test3"}]  
}

Object.values(obj).filter((ob, i)=>{if(ob[0].id === input){console.log(Object.keys(obj)[i])}})
```